# Need alternative field names for these reserved words

Tags: database-design, reserved-words

“type” and “class” are likely reserved or problematic words in C# and/or Ruby, two languages I may use to program against my new database schema in the future.

So, in order to avoid potential conflicts with those languages, I’m looking for alternative names for these field names in my tables.

In this case, it is from my Machines table, where I have:

“class” field (values would be something like “manual” or “computerized”)

and

“type” field (values would be “lathe” or “mill”)

I could call the fields “machineclass” and “machinetype”, but that is inconsistent with naming scheme in the rest of my schema (meaning, I do not re-use the table name in the field…  For instance, I use Machine.name, not Machine.machinename)

Any thought on this madness?

Comment: This should be on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

You might add some redundancy and call them "type_id" and "class_id", or "type_name" and "class_name".

Answer (score 2):

Simple.  it happens in SQL as well, all the time.  You need a naming for that particular problem, while not breaking the larger naming convention you have chosen.

Our naming convention (which has the same issue as yours, resolved) would dictate something like this.  Easy to read and understand, but also identifying that we are avoiding a reserved word confilct:

Classs
Typpe

We already have:

Rowss
Countt

MachineClass and MachineType would be wrong.

Comment: is there a pattern in _which_ letter you double?

Comment: @Tyr: Yes, the consonant at the end.  It jumps out at you as a harmless misspelling of the intended term.  Whereas substitutions 'K' instead of 'C' and tend to grate, and doubling a vowel changes the word drastically: Typee, Roows.

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm bilingual (English and Spanish) I use: clase = class, tipo = type, or if I want to keep everything in english, I'll choose a synonym like: category = class, kind = type.  I also concatenate _v1 _v2 _v3 ... to column names when I make revisions or new versions to my apps which require new columns to more easily document my code.

Answer (score 0):

Klass is a common misspelling of class that could be used.
I'm not sure if a good misspelling of type exist though.

Klass might be used by Ruby On Rails though, I'm not sure.  I would double check that before using klass, as I wouldn't want to shadow its variables.

Comment: Yucky?  I though it was rather klassy. ;)

Answer (score 0):

generally we resolve  it by appending _id

so the lookup table would have `Machine_Types.type_id, Machine_Types.name`

and `Machine.type_id` would tie back easily on `join Machine_Types  using(type_id)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see any problems with database fields being called 'type' or 'class' - at least from C# point of view. Most ORM mappers will generate classes with properties called 'type' and 'class', which is legal. If you use DataReader you will use indexer and field names will be passed as strings.

I can't think of any case when your database field name would 'clash' with C# keyword.

Answer (score -1):

Not a great solution, but C# is case-sensitive. You can have a variable or a class named Class or Type, and it won't conflict with the class or type reserved words.

Comment: I would very much disagree with that "solution" as it will lead to confusion when reading the code.  Besides, messing up your capitalization scheme seems worse than adding _id to the names

Comment: I was thinking I disagreed with that at first, hence the "not a great solution", but Microsoft already has a type called Type (in the System namespace), so it can't be that bad, but you will have to worry about namespace collisions. Oh, and I wouldn't want to mess up the capitalization scheme either, but properties (and some might say public fields) should already be capitalized.

Comment: To show how bad an idea this is, this was suggested in a question about evil coding on programmers.SE.

Comment: and Jakub's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149623/need-alternative-field-names-for-these-reserved-words/4149672#4149672 is perfectly acceptable? Microsoft has a type named "Type". If you think it's so bad, then you probably shouldn't use C#, as it was designed by bad programmers.

Comment: Well, he also mentioned ruby, where making it a capital would make it a constant or class name.  Much less fun.